# IDEA prepends server args

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am expecting the second argument to my main method to be the location of a json file. This works fine when I call the app from the command line, which is how it will be deployed by our ops team. But when I try to call the app using IDEA, it prepends a bunch of other args to the args that go into my main method, and I'm not getting the json file location in the second argument. When I output the args to stderr, I see:

```
-Didea.launcher.port=7540
-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 11.app/bin
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:blahblahblah:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-oxm/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-oxm-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 11.app/lib/idea_rt.jar
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain
com.pronto.JettyWebApp
server
path/to/app.json
```

(I've substantially abridged the classpath for readability.)

Here's the Run/Debug configs screen in IDEA:

[image]

How do I prevent IDEA from prepending these extra args to my app?

Comment: How are you getting and printing out the args? This seems weird because only the arguments after com.pronto.JettyWebApp should be passed as program arguments to main method, rest are VM arguments. I just tried this on a Hello World program and none of the arguments like -classpath were in my args when i run it.

Comment: I had a for loop in my main method that printed them out. I was surprised to see them too. Did you run your helloworld program inside IDEA as an app also?

Comment: Yes I did. Can you reproduce this behavior on some new blank Hello World project just to rule out some issues with the configuration of your particular project in IntelliJ?

Comment: Good idea, will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the first line of my main method where I instantiate org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.

```
public class JettyWebApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server();

        if (args == null) {
            System.err.println(errorMessage + ": args == null");
            throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage);
        }
        String jsonFile = "";
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.err.println(arg);
            if (StringUtils.contains(arg, ".json")) {
                jsonFile = arg;
                break;
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

A short test app like the following outputs only the args I submit to it in the IDEA config.

```
public class TestForArgs {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args == null) {
            System.out.println("args == null");
        }
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```